# passing params with checkboxes in forms Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox

So i'm hitting my head on this. I want to have a checkbox that sends Time.now to my database under the featured column.

I know how to pass params using check_box_tag and that seems to pass as seen below:

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"24aw2xi68XsgMrU28is3wcXkNdhLlgVHhZBuJdd9984=", "article"=>{"body"=>"oops", "published"=>"0", "headline"=>"headlinez", "input_slug"=>"weee", "article_position"=>"5", "issue_id"=>"1", "section_id"=>"1", "author_id"=>"", "flag"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Save Article", "featured"=>"2014-01-25 19:28:57 -0800", "id"=>"weee"}
```

But how can i get that to pass from WITHIN article? check_box_tag seems to not be liked by forms, so how do you do it?

Here is my form:

```
<div class="field">
        <label>Featured Article?</label>
        <%= check_box_tag :featured, @time %>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To move the parameter to be within the article hash, you can name the check_box_tag something like this

```
<%= check_box_tag 'article[featured]', @time %>
```

EDIT - Adding more to this answer since you're using form_for

You can do this sort of thing, since you have an @article and a 'featured' method...

```
<%= f.check_box :featured, {}, Time.now %> # As you wrote in your answer
```

But, you can also do this, which is a little more Rails standard...

Change 'featured' to be featured_at (this is the more standard way of indicating a datetime), and add a 'featured' attr_access to article.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessor :featured

def featured
  !!featured_at
end

def featured=(value)
  if featured_at.present? && value.blank?
    self.featured_at = nil
  elsif featured_at.blank? && value.present?
    self.featured_at = Time.now
  end
end
```

And then, you can submit a boolean via the form for `featured`, instead of a datetime.

```
= f.check_box :featured, {}, 'true', ''
```

This is less prone to any sort of hacking.  That may not matter here, just a good practice.

Comment: ah, i see, i was trying many different ways similar to that but that's the syntax i needed thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to do this the following way

```
<%= f.check_box :featured, {}, Time.now %>
```